# Cannot get error 500 details in controller

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, try-catch

I have a simple Rest Web service that raises an exception randomly (Internal Server Error).
I noticed it when I have stressed this Web api in a console program in a 50.000 iterations loop.
What I get in this client :

---

{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,

---

What I want is to get this Error 500 detail.
But I cannot catch it in my controller, the code doesn't go in the catch.
The controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("{IdLog}/message")]
    public string CreateLogMsg(long IdLog, [FromBody] TlogLineDTO oLogLine)
    {
        long lTmp = 0;

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string sTmp = _oExploitBll.InsertNewLogLine(oLogLine).ToString();

                if (!long.TryParse(sTmp, out lTmp))
                {
                    // Create a new file     
                    Random rnd = new Random();

                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"E:\Temp\20200707\REF_" + rnd.Next().ToString() + ".txt"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(sTmp);
                    }
                }
                return sTmp;
            }
            else
            {
                // Create a new file where to put the error message   
                Random rnd = new Random();

                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"E:\Temp\20200707\REF_" + rnd.Next().ToString() + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Ko");
                }

                return "Ko";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string sMsgErr = ex.Message + "-" + ex.StackTrace;

            // Create a new file     
            Random rnd = new Random();

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"E:\Temp\20200707\REF_" + rnd.Next().ToString() + ".txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sMsgErr);
            }
            return "0";
        }          
    }
```

How can I make it go in the catch ?
Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Eric

Comment: use break point to debug your code :)

Comment: Akbar Asghari : thanks for your comment. I would find it funny if I was not stuck in it for  a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I have corrected the code and added a loop of 2 retries for the http requests and it seems to work : when the http request fails, I retry it once (or the number of retries I want) and generally the http request success in the second retry.
But I still don't know why the http requests fail sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, the error happens because the server is too stressed the requests which get the error never reach the controller. Actually the server cannot even enqueue them. Sso you can't handle them unless you add a side-car server which receives requests from the client, forwards them to your server and then

- if response is ok forwards response to client
- else handles the error

In real case scenarios you use a load balancer to divide the request load between more servers

Comment: Thank you for your reply @user3415993. I missed to say that I have such errors in production environment for that Web service. That is why I run this loop in Dev environement to raise those errors and detect what they are in details.

Comment: Then you should give a look to your web server logo and see if the error is always relatore to the same request or not. Could it Be related to a huge load of requests?

Comment: ddfra : 
The error is not relative to the same request.
The number of request to the web service is not huge in comparison to the stress program.